# What does page.driver.reset! do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, browser-cache

I'm running a Capybara(poltergeist) test that is sensitive to cached files in the browser. I want to test to ensure that if a user is visiting the page without a cache, they can see a form.

```
context 'when user on page with empty cache' do
  scenario 'sees form' do
    page.driver.reset!
    visit home_path
    # test to see if form exists
  end
end
```

My question is this. Does `page.driver.reset!` reset the browser cache?

Comment: page.driver.reset! is dependent on which driver you're using - Are you using the default rack-test driver, or selenium, or capybara-webkit, or poltergeist?

Comment: I'm using poltergeist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Poltergeist Driver#reset! doesn't clear the browser cache, but as long as you're running Poltergeist 1.10+ you can make sure it's cleared for your test by calling

```
page.driver.clear_memory_cache
```

Comment: I'm running Poltergeist 1.9 but when I ran that code Poltergeist responded with an undefined method error.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice `1.10`. Updating and testing this now.